# Вычисление факториала на ассемблерной вставке с помощью рекурсии

Tags: c++, ассемблер, рекурсия

Задание требует именно ассемблерной вставки.
Ниже мой код, который вызывает переполнение, как я понимаю. Но вот как написать правильно, что-то не могу найти.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3, b;
    __asm
    {
        push a
        mov eax, 1
        call fact
        mov b, eax

        jmp exit1

        fact :
        pop a
        mov ecx,a
            mul ecx
            dec ecx
            cmp ecx, 1
            jne exit2
            call fact
            ret

            exit1 :
            exit2:
    }

    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы делаете **goto** с `jne fact`, а надо **call**. условный  **call** может быть есть, надо посмотреть

Comment: @AlexGlebe изменил код, так оно выдает ответ в районе -858993460

Comment: со стеком вообще дурдом, заносите с **push**, **не** извлекаете с **pop**, а просто прямо смотрите в мусор стека `mov ecx, [esp + 4]`. начните с простого.

Comment: @AlexGlebe будет `pop a` , ошибка все та же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так устроит?

```
int a = 7, b;
__asm
{
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,a
    call fact
    jmp quit

fact:
    cmp eax,1
    jle exitfact
    imul ebx,eax
    dec eax
    call fact
exitfact:
    ret
quit:
    mov b, ebx
}

std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Comment: Я не указал этого, моя ошибка, по заданию нужно работать со стеком. Поэтому я его использую. Заменил в вашем коде строчку `mov eax,a` на две строки `push a` `mov eax,[esp]`, чтобы хоть где-то стек был, но все равно не работает. Я понял свою ошибку, что я каждый раз в функции вытаскивал и записывал при вызове, но тут я даже попытался за факториал вынести, все равно не работает.

Comment: Но в любом случае вы точно помогли, про стек я не указывал, может разберусь откуда ошибка